# How to proceed when a professor is not answering emails requesting for a grade? and not awarding bonus points as he said?

Tags: masters, email, grades

Some key facts:

- I am a master's student.
- The professor in question is also our **director of studies** and teaches 3 mandatory classes in our program.
- Several students have sent emails that never received a reply.

The situation:

The professor in question is not answering emails regarding the grades for two of the seminars. I contacted this professor by email about two weeks ago to know what was my grade for the last project and to have feedback on what I did well/wrong and also to know how was the class graded in general, but I never received a reply. At this point, I will like to mention that other students have also emailed this teacher about the same topic and to this date, no one has received an answer. Yet, he does answer emails for other type of inquiries we might have.

This brings me to next point, it appears to be that in both of the seminars **he did not add in the grade bonus points we were promised** (as a matter of fact, he was the one proposing the bonus points after some of us complained directly to him about the tasks\projects in question).

At last, if we know our final grade is because the department sends them to each student once the professor has given them the final grade which in the case of this professor it took about **2 months longer than the rest of the seminars**. The issue here is that we never got the grade for the last project we did in both of the seminars, but only got a final grade. Therefore, there was no possibility to know if the grade for the project was fair and it has not been possible to have some feedback on why we got the given grade.

At this point, I am pondering whether it is necessary to *contact an Ombudsperson* from the university or to resend him an email or contact him personally instead of escalating the situation?

Thank you for your valuable feedback on this matter.

Comment: Does this class have a teaching assistant whom you can contact?

Comment: Have you tried asking in person?

Comment: Your key facts should include when the grades *should* be submitted. Does it say anything in the syllabus? Do they need to be submitted by the end of term or some period after the term? This will affect how you should approach the situation. If the professor is in clear violation of some written policy that's very different from the professor being on the slower side of acceptable. You make it very clear that *you* don't think it's within the acceptable range, but your key facts don't include a timeline for when marks should be awarded / uploaded and what kind of feedback is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, contact the ombudsperson, student office or office of graduate studies about this. If several of you do so then it’ll probably make the department push the Professor to do their job. Professors often see their teaching duties as secondary but this seems particularly egregious.

Hope it gets straightened out. I had a professor who failed to submit grades for nearly a year, eventually the entire class got an A- blanket grade which was infuriating.